# How to unify in one record (grouped by date) the data when every couple of columns are in different rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to unify in only one record (grouped by date) every couple of columns are in different rows in Postgresql?

Here is the example I'm talking about:

| **id** | **emp_id** | **name** | **work_date** | **work_start_time** | **attendance_start_time** | **start_lunch** | **attendance_start_lunch** | **end_lunch** | **attendance_end_lunch** | **work_end_time** | **attendance_end_time** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | Johm Smith | 2019-05-30 | 08:00:00 AM | 07:58:34 AM |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 100 | Johm Smith | 2019-05-30 |  |  | 01:00:00 PM | 01:03:25 PM |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 100 | Johm Smith | 2019-05-30 |  |  |  |  | 01:03:25 PM | 01:38:24 PM |  |  |
| 4 | 100 | Johm Smith | 2019-05-30 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 05:00:00 PM | 05:03:35 PM |
| 5 | 100 | Johm Smith | 2019-05-31 | 08:00:00 AM | 07:48:00 AM |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 6 | 100 | Johm Smith | 2019-05-31 |  |  | 01:00:00 PM | 01:05:32 PM |  |  |  |  |
| 7 | 100 | Johm Smith | 2019-05-31 |  |  |  |  | 02:00:00 PM | 01:51:00 PM |  |  |
| 8 | 100 | Johm Smith | 2019-05-31 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 05:00:00 PM | 05:08:00 PM |
| 9 | 100 | Johm Smith | 2019-06-03 | 08:00:00 AM | 08:03:30 AM |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 10 | 100 | Johm Smith | 2019-06-03 |  |  | 01:00:00 PM | 01:04:58 PM |  |  |  |  |
| 11 | 100 | Johm Smith | 2019-06-03 |  |  |  |  | 02:00:00 PM | 01:50:03 PM |  |  |
| 12 | 100 | Johm Smith | 2019-06-03 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 05:00:00 PM | 05:47:09 PM |
| 13 | 100 | Johm Smith | 2019-06-04 | 08:00:00 AM | 08:00:38 AM |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 14 | 100 | Johm Smith | 2019-06-04 |  |  | 01:00:00 PM | 01:04:56 PM |  |  |  |  |
| 15 | 100 | Johm Smith | 2019-06-04 |  |  |  |  | 02:00:00 PM | 01:50:27 PM |  |  |
| 16 | 100 | Johm Smith | 2019-06-04 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 05:00:00 PM | 05:06:43 PM |
| 17 | 101 | William Davies | 2019-08-12 | 08:00:00 AM | 07:03:45 AM |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 18 | 101 | William Davies | 2019-08-12 |  |  | 01:00:00 PM | 01:00:33 PM |  |  |  |  |
| 19 | 101 | William Davies | 2019-08-12 |  |  |  |  | 02:00:33 PM | 02:57:04 PM |  |  |
| 20 | 101 | William Davies | 2019-08-12 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 05:00:00 PM | 05:04:20 PM |
| 21 | 101 | William Davies | 2019-08-13 | 08:00:00 AM | 06:57:44 AM |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 22 | 101 | William Davies | 2019-08-13 |  |  | 01:00:00 PM | 01:12:37 PM |  |  |  |  |
| 23 | 101 | William Davies | 2019-08-13 |  |  |  |  | 02:12:37 PM | 02:57:30 PM |  |  |
| 24 | 101 | William Davies | 2019-08-13 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 05:00:00 PM | 05:01:24 PM |
| 25 | 101 | William Davies | 2019-08-14 | 08:00:00 AM | 07:02:02 AM |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 26 | 101 | William Davies | 2019-08-14 |  |  | 01:00:00 PM | 01:05:57 PM |  |  |  |  |
| 27 | 101 | William Davies | 2019-08-14 |  |  |  |  | 02:05:57 PM | 02:59:24 PM |  |  |
| 28 | 101 | William Davies | 2019-08-14 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 05:00:00 PM | 05:03:58 PM |
| 29 | 101 | William Davies | 2019-08-15 | 08:00:00 AM | 07:03:53 AM |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 30 | 101 | William Davies | 2019-08-15 |  |  | 01:00:00 PM | 01:03:57 PM |  |  |  |  |
| 31 | 101 | William Davies | 2019-08-15 |  |  |  |  | 02:03:57 PM | 03:10:19 PM |  |  |
| 32 | 101 | William Davies | 2019-08-15 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 05:00:00 PM | 05:07:47 PM |

| **id** | **emp_id** | **name** | **work_date** | **work_start_time** | **attendance_start_time** | **start_lunch** | **attendance_start_lunch** | **end_lunch** | **attendance_end_lunch** | **work_end_time** | **attendance_end_time** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | Johm Smith | 2019-05-30 | 08:00:00 AM | 07:58:34 AM | 01:00:00 PM | 01:03:25 PM | 01:03:25 PM | 01:38:24 PM | 05:00:00 PM | 05:03:35 PM |
| 2 | 100 | Johm Smith | 2019-05-31 | 08:00:00 AM | 07:48:00 AM | 01:00:00 PM | 01:05:32 PM | 02:00:00 PM | 01:51:00 PM | 05:00:00 PM | 05:08:00 PM |
| 3 | 100 | Johm Smith | 2019-06-03 | 08:00:00 AM | 08:03:30 AM | 01:00:00 PM | 01:04:58 PM | 02:00:00 PM | 01:50:03 PM | 05:00:00 PM | 05:47:09 PM |
| 4 | 100 | Johm Smith | 2019-06-04 | 08:00:00 AM | 08:00:38 AM | 01:00:00 PM | 01:04:56 PM | 02:00:00 PM | 01:50:27 PM | 05:00:00 PM | 05:06:43 PM |
| 5 | 101 | William Davies | 2019-08-12 | 08:00:00 AM | 07:03:45 AM | 01:00:00 PM | 01:00:33 PM | 02:00:33 PM | 02:57:04 PM | 05:00:00 PM | 05:04:20 PM |
| 6 | 101 | William Davies | 2019-08-13 | 08:00:00 AM | 06:57:44 AM | 01:00:00 PM | 01:12:37 PM | 02:12:37 PM | 02:57:30 PM | 05:00:00 PM | 05:01:24 PM |
| 7 | 101 | William Davies | 2019-08-14 | 08:00:00 AM | 07:02:02 AM | 01:00:00 PM | 01:05:57 PM | 02:05:57 PM | 02:59:24 PM | 05:00:00 PM | 05:03:58 PM |
| 8 | 101 | William Davies | 2019-08-15 | 08:00:00 AM | 07:03:53 AM | 01:00:00 PM | 01:03:57 PM | 02:03:57 PM | 03:10:19 PM | 05:00:00 PM | 05:07:47 PM |

Comment: There are a lot of "holes" in your database, why are the rows duplicated with empty values? before making a complex request better ask why your database is not normalized. Next if your data is line-oriented, you can check transposition method, if you still keep the data this way, you will have to use probably auto-joins (or grouping function like in the answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with the long, boring way:

```
select
  emp_id, name, work_date,
  max(work_start_time) as work_start_time,
  max(attendance_start_time) as attendance_start_time,
  max(start_lunch) as start_lunch,
  max(attendance_start_lunch) as attendance_start_lunch,
  max(end_lunch) as end_lunch,
  max(attendance_end_lunch) as attendance_end_lunch
  max(work_end_time) as work_end_time,
  max(attendance_end_time) as attendance_end_time
from t
group by emp_id, name, work_date
```